# Google Adsense Laravel Project ads.txt found but empty page

Tags: php, laravel

My Google Adsense Laravel Project have ads.txt on public directory it looks likes it found when visiting the URL but empty page.

Here is the link
https://laravelgenerator.online/ads.txt

Mean while I just put laravel blade to it and have Route::('ads.txt');
then displays the view file ads.txt content

I want it to be accessible on the public folder. so I can get rid on the route I made for ads.txt.